# Add existing project to solution with files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How can I add a project I have developed separately to my current solution including all its project files? When I select *Add existing project* in my solution explorer, the project is added but I don't see the project files in my solution folder.

Comment: It won't *move* or *copy* the project and its files into the folder where the solution is, it will just essentially refer to the other folder.

Comment: Yet, adding an existing file to your project _will_ copy it into your project (and not simply reference it). Just throwing that out there, in case that behavior is what led to your confusion.

Comment: @GrantWinney I mean the solution folder on VS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on some version of Visual Studio, then I think that you can't do what you are asking. However you can manually copy the project to wherever you need it to be, and then add it to the former solution.

Answer (score 0):

It worked out for me. Manually copy or move new project to existing project and right click on project and then add existing solution, then select new project which we copied